# Attack not being counted in clan war

Tags: clash-of-clans

My attack in clan war is not getting counted. Most of the time, only one attack gets counted and the second one does not.

My troops are gone but I don't get any loot and still it shows 1 attack remaining.

I am using BlueStacks on my laptop to play Clash of Clans. I have experienced this problem for some days.

Comment: Did you actually win the attack? Also, has someone else attacked on the smae base and gotten a higher score than you? And what do you mean by 'not being counted'?

Comment: I mean after attacking the base it still shows 2 attacks remaining

Comment: No idea. I use BlueStacks too on my laptop and no problem here. Do you possibly use mods?

Comment: Yep i use mts modem

Comment: I guess its connection problem

Comment: Tried restarting your game? (Sounds like a desync issue - You attacked while disconnected; so your attack was never counted (or ignored by the system due to 0%ing), thus troop never used(?))?

Comment: Bluestacks is known is be very buggy and it's still in its experimental stage.  Stick with the stable Android and iOS versions if you want best reliability.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your connection get disconnected every once in a while and the game doesn't immediately kick you out if that happens. It tries to reconnect a few times before it gives up. I think during your attack you were offline and that's why it didn't register the attack.

If you ever see this wifi-looking icon in the middle of your screen then that means it's trying to reconnect:
[image]

Comment: Wait how do you have the old Gold 3? I want that :(

Comment: @bleh: That's an old screenshot I think. The clan castle has the old graphic too.

Comment: Yeah. It's an old screenshot. @bleh